# split up every hour by multiple activities using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

trying split hours into 5 breakups using excel VBA. Need to capture the time frame 10:00 - 11:00 may occupy such activities like 10mnts break, 30mnts production, and 20mnts idle. I googled/compiled the below code and got stuck by run-time error 1004. It is ok with all the algorithms except for the placement of activities.

```
Sub split_Interval_by_Activity()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Testing")

LastRow = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For MyRow = 4 To LastRow
   sLookFor_Name = Ws1.Range("A" & MyRow)
   sLookFor_Activity = Ws1.Range("D" & MyRow)

If Ws2.Cells(MyRow, "A") = sLookFor_Name And Ws2.Cells(MyRow, "D") = sLookFor_Activity Then
    If sLookFor_Activity = "Production" Then curCol = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 2
    If sLookFor_Activity = "Idle" Then curCol = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 3
    If sLookFor_Activity = "Noload" Then curCol = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 4
    If sLookFor_Activity = "Tech" Then curCol = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 5
    If sLookFor_Activity = "Break" Then curCol = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 6
        
    hour1 = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
    If Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) < hour1 Then
        hour2 = Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) + 24
    Else: hour2 = Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
    End If
    
    If hour1 <> hour2 Then
        minute1 = Minute(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
        minute2 = Minute(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
        second1 = Second(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
        second2 = Second(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
        
        Do Until curCol = hour2 + 2
            curTime = 1 - ((minute1 / 60) + (second1 / 3600))
            If curCol - 2 = hour1 Then
                Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(Fix(curTime), Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60), _
                Fix((((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60) - Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60)) * 60))
            Else: Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
            End If
            curCol = curCol + 5
        Loop
        curTime = (minute2 / 60) + (second2 / 3600)
        Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(Fix(curTime), Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60), _
        Fix((((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60) - Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60)) * 60))
    Else
        Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value - Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value
    End If
End If
Next MyRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

help me to have free of mind struggling.

Note: for the night hours (23:00-07:00) need to add 24 with hour1 variable to find out curCol .

Input:
[image: sample_data_info]

Output:
[image: desired_output]

Comment: An example of both your input data and desired output would be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```vb
Sub split_Interval_by_Activity()
    Const colBegin As Long = 9 'Column where the second table in Testing begins
    Const hourBegin As Long = 7 'Hour the second table in Testing begins with
    
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim sLookFor_Name As Range
    Dim sLookFor_Activity As Range
    Dim sDiff As Long
    Dim sOffset As Long
    Dim sRemainder As Long
    Dim hour1 As Long
    Dim hour2 As Long
    Dim minute1 As Long
    Dim minute2 As Long
    Dim second1 As Long
    Dim second2 As Long
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim curCol As Long
    

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Testing")
    
    LastRow = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For MyRow = 4 To LastRow
        Set sLookFor_Name = Ws1.Range("A" & MyRow)
        Set sLookFor_Activity = Ws1.Range("D" & MyRow)
    
        If Ws2.Cells(MyRow, "A") = sLookFor_Name And Ws2.Cells(MyRow, "D") = sLookFor_Activity Then
            hour1 = Hour(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
            
            If Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) < hour1 Then
                hour2 = Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) + 24
            Else
                hour2 = Hour(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
            End If
            
            If sLookFor_Activity = "Production" Then curCol = colBegin
            If sLookFor_Activity = "Idle" Then curCol = colBegin + 1
            If sLookFor_Activity = "Noload" Then curCol = colBegin + 2
            If sLookFor_Activity = "Tech" Then curCol = colBegin + 3
            If sLookFor_Activity = "Break" Then curCol = colBegin + 4
            
            If hour1 <> hour2 Then
                minute1 = Minute(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
                minute2 = Minute(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
                second1 = Second(Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
                second2 = Second(Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
                                
                sDiff = ((hour2 - hour1) * 3600) + ((minute2 - minute1) * 60) + (second2 - second1)
                sOffset = (minute1 * 60) + second1
                sRemainder = 3600 - sOffset
                curCol = curCol + ((hour1 - hourBegin) * 5)
                
                Do Until sDiff = 0
                    If sOffset <> 0 Then
                        Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(0, 0, sRemainder)
                        sDiff = sDiff - sRemainder
                        sOffset = 0
                        curCol = curCol + 5
                    
                    ElseIf 3600 < sDiff Then
                        Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
                        sDiff = sDiff - 3600
                        curCol = curCol + 5
                    Else
                        Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(0, 0, sDiff)
                        sDiff = 0
                    End If
                Loop
            Else
                Ws2.Cells(MyRow, curCol).Value = Ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value - Ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next MyRow
End Sub
```

In your code, the `Do Until` loop would keep going without any end, causing the error 1004. I found it simpler to rewrite that part. The way it works now is that for each row, it first finds the difference in seconds (`sDiff`) between the start and end times. Then it loops through the columns of the second table in Testing. It writes the correct duration for the current hour, then subtracts that from the difference. It repeats in this loop until the difference is 0.